# Enable multi user management in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

In the table **users** a MySql db for each user can be stored with a different color, for example:

```
Users       colors
Foo         green
Pluto       yellow
Foo         red
```

When the user is authenticated I need to know what color is associated with the user who logs on.

I used the List method to append the variable color for each user in this way:

```
List<string> colorList = new List<string>();

....

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Colors = reader["Colors"].ToString();
        colorList.Add(Colors.ToString());
    }

        ns = string.Join(", ", colorList.ToArray());
}
```

And everything works up here.

Now I need publish in a **GridView** all rows stored in **Experience table** where are stored the comments of all users for each color.

For example in the case of **user Foo** I need publish in **GridView** all comments stored in **Experience table** speaking of the **colors red and green**.

But I can't publish this **GridView** because if user is **Foo** I see only the comments on the **red color** and nothing comment for **green color**.

Thought with loop I have this output:

```
SELECT * FROM Experience WHERE Colors IN ('red');

SELECT * FROM Experience WHERE Colors IN ('green');
```

My code below.

Anybody know how can I resolve do this?

Can you suggest?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

```
private DataSet RetrieveColors()
    {
        str = null;
        strArr = null;
        count = 0;

        str = ns == null ? "" : ns.ToString();
        char[] splitchar = { ',' };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            strArr = str.Split(splitchar);
        }
        else
        {
            strArr = null;
        }

        for (count = 0; count <= strArr.Length - 1; count++)
        {
                sql = @" SELECT * FROM Experience WHERE Colors IN (?); ";
        }


        DataSet dsColors = new DataSet();

        using (OdbcConnection cn =
          new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();

            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
            {
                for (count = 0; count <= strArr.Length - 1; count++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", Server.UrlDecode(strArr[count].Trim()));
                }

                OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dsColors);
            }
        }

        return dsColors;
    }
```

**Edit # 1**

```
Users       colors
Foo         green
Pluto       yellow
Foo         red
```

Comment: please show a sample of the Experience table columns and the expected output.

Comment: @BlackBaron Please see *Edit # 1* in my first question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
sql = @" SELECT * FROM Experience WHERE Colors IN (?";

for (count = 1; count <= strArr.Length - 1; count++)
        {
                sql += ",?"; // add more placeholders as needed
        }
sql+=");"
```